Cannot set Spectrum Color Picker to null or no color
I am trying to set the Spectrum Color Picker to its initial state so no color is set but I cant get it working by setting the Spectrum Color Picker to null, like this:
$("#stylecolor").spectrum("set", null);

Am I missing anything, so how to I set the Spectrum Color Picker to empty or null?

Please include your HTML/CSS to provide a working example that demonstrates the issue. Have you tried options for showInitial? You might also try setting an empty string instead of null; see set().
